# SQL Server Instance not showing in Visual Studio while connection

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

When I add a new connection in visual studio, then in the server name it is not showing `a-9\MSSQLSERVER`, it shows `a-9\sqlexpress` and `a-9\new` but I want to connect to MSSQLSERVER.

But when I change the data source to Microsoft ODBC Data Source then it shows the instance MSSQLSERVER.

But when I choose Data Source as "Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)" or "Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)" then it gives error "Network related instance error."

Comment: Is the server on a different box? If so, have you enabled TCP and Named Pipes protocols on the server? Do you have a firewall on the server machine and have you punched a hole for SQL Browser and the SQL Server services? Are you able to connect to the server using SSMS?

Comment: Have you tried "(localhost)" or simply "."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is something called SQL SERVER DATA TOOLS 2012.  If I add my SQL Server to this tool than it appears in the Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2012. This solved my problem.